# Suggestion: Notification for accepting answer to your question

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications, new-users

I think we have many new people asking their questions on one of the Stack Exchange sites. These new people are not completely aware of voting up and accepting answers.

I think it would be great if a notification is shown to the user if his/her question has at least one upvoted answer, because the Stack Exchange community encourages accepting answers.

Comment: Something like this could work, especially for new users. Maybe kill the notification once you gain enough rep? It already gives a notification for new answers, so once someone's been around a while, they'll know what to do. Otherwise, it could get seriously annoying for people who ask a lot of questions.

Comment: I would send the notification if he has at least one upvoted answer after like 1 or 2 days. Just to remember him, but not to force him accepting right away. If we send it right away new users might tend to accept the first answer even though it might not solve their answers

Comment: New users cannot vote yet, not until you have 15 rep. New users *are* reminded that you can accept an answer already, IIRC.

Comment: -1 This has been debated over and over.  Let them read the FAQ and watch their own questions.

Comment: By the way, when you're a new user and you upvote an answer to your question, you do get a notification about accepting the answer. I think it only happens once, but then... once you learn it, no reason to show it again.

Comment: I don't think the possible dupe is correct.  The title is close, but the question text doesn't even match the title.

Comment: @LanceRoberts agreed, reopened the question.